# What is the difference in research culture between a University of X and a X University of Technology?

Tags: research-process, university

In various parts of Europe (even in Israel) I see that there are two types of universities:

1. [University of 'X'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/University_of_Warsaw)
2. ['X' University of Technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_University_of_Technology)

where X is the name of a city.

The main difference I discovered is: #2 offers more jobs in the industry, but #1 offers more research opportunity.

Do they follow different types of cultures in terms of teaching and research? Do they follow different quality standards?

Comment: I think there are no standard differences or rules about the names of HE institutes like this.

Comment: Note that in the specific case you link, they're not two separate institutions. The first link is the University of Lisbon, the second is the school of engineering, which is also part of the University of Lisbon.

Comment: As usual, asking about "the EU" is too broad, this varies considerably by country.

Answer (score 3):

Historically speaking, it's possible there would have been differences between what the universities researched or were built to research and thus were given different names. However, research directions and capabilities change over time and I don't think it's possible to draw such distinctions based on name alone these days. Research "quality" or "standards" can also be somewhat subjective, and will definitely vary from country to country.